# Optional templated method argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a code that creates the objects. Each object can consist of any number of modules and optionally a configuration. To cover both cases I had to create two methods (below is a "scenario" code).

```
template <typename Impl, typename ... Modules>
Impl create(Ioc& ioc)
{
    return Impl{ioc.create<Modules>()...};
}
```

Too add optional configuration, another version has to be written

```
template <typename Impl, typename Config, typename ... Modules>
Impl create(Ioc& ioc, const Config& config)
{
    return Impl{ioc.create<Modules>()..., config};
}
```

Is it possible to somehow create one method that would cover both cases?

Comment: Sure, your first `create` should call the second with a default config object. That way your real implementation is only in one place.

Comment: I understand, but that way all objects created this way would have to accept some `Config` in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple parameter packs if you put the Config last:

```
template <typename Impl, typename... Modules, typename... Config>
Impl create(Ioc& ioc, Config const& ... config) {
  return Impl{ioc.create<Modules>()..., config ...};
}
```

You can also split the parameter packs using a lambda:

```
template <typename Impl, typename ... Modules>
auto create = [](Ioc& ioc, auto const& ... config) -> Impl {
    return Impl{ioc.create<Modules>()..., config ...};
};
```

This will accept any number of parameters after the first `Config`. To enforce only zero on one extra arguments, add

```
static_assert(sizeof...(config) <= 1);
```

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof...(Config) <= 1);`? :)

Comment: This doesnt really work. Compiler cannot deduce where configs end and modules start.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer and tested it this time around: https://godbolt.org/z/sr5KVk

Comment: @Croolman Just out of curiosity, why does the first approach not work? Shouldn't it be fixed by swapping the two parameter packs? [Compilerexplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/2xrLAE). Then it should work even for a c++03 compiler if I'm not mistaken.